# Обработка ошибок PHP при помощи Nginx и вывод заранее подготовленной страницы

Tags: php, nginx

Привет. Заметил, что при ошибках PHP вместо сайта просто белая страница, а ошибка `500 Internal Server Error` отображается лишь в консоли. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при наличии ошибок в PHP отображалась заранее подготовленная страница?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в секцию server

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
location = /custom_50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
}
```

Comment: Что делает `internal`?

Comment: Указывает, что этот location для внутренних запросов только, типа error_page.